# Do I need to use he twice in this sentence?

Tags: ellipsis, redundancy

Can I say:

He turned around and was greeted with a smile from his frend.

Or do I have to use he twice?

He turned around and he was greeted with a smile from his friend.

Comment: No, you don't have to use _he_ twice, and yes, you can leave off the second _he_, if you want to; or, you can leave it in. The optional (but very frequently applied) rule is called [_Conjunction Reduction_](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299).

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is correct. You can link two predicates with the same subject with a conjunction. Consider "He laughed and cried". "He ate and was full". "He turned and was greeted".

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct.  However, in everyday speech it sounds more natural to say:

> He turned around and was greeted with a smile from his friend.

This is because we already know who the subject of the sentence is, so it isn't necessary to repeat 'he'.  That said, it isn't grammatically incorrect to repeat it, either.